# Удаление из списка

Tags: c++

К своей задаче я написал такую функцию удаления

```
void Delete(list *head, list* &tail)
{

    list *T, *P;

    P = head;
    T = head->next;
    while (T->next != tail)
    {
        if (T->info == P->info)
            P->next = T->next; // если элементы одинаковые то убираю 2 одинаковый
        else
            P=T; // если разные то двигаюсь дальше
        T = T->next;

    }
    if (tail->info == T->info) // рассматриваю последний и предпоследний
    {
        T->next = NULL; // если одинаковые то последний убираю
        tail = T;
    }
}
```

вроде все предусмотрел, но на выходе желаемого результата нет (допустим, ввел 8 единиц, то получается 2 единицы, а не одна, когда в некоторых случаях все получается (например, ввожу 1 2 2 3 3 выходит 123). Укажите, пожалуйста на ошибку.

Comment: Я там на Ваш вопрос "динамические структуры" немножко ответил.

Answer (score 2):

Код ошибочный

1. Не рассматривается случай, когда список состоит из одного элемента, то есть `head->next` равно `NULL`.
2. Идет утечка памяти по тем элементам, которые исключены из списка.
3. Аргумент `tail` не нужен. Точнее он нужен только лишь если дубликаты нужно искать не во всем списке, а в его части. А конец списка всегда можно распознать по тому, что для последнего элемента указатель `next` будет установлен в `NULL`.
4. Есть лишние переменные. Тот же указатель `P` не нужен, так как указатель `head` в функции изменить нельзя. А можно только изменить данные по указателю `head`
   ро.
5. Ну, и до кучи — алгоритм слишком навернут. Нет необходимости отдельно рассматривать последний и предпоследний элемент. Так же как и первый и второй. Попробуйте вручную прогнать алгоритм для списка из двух одинаковых элементов — думаю, все поймете

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример работающей функции, переработаешь под свой пример. Сложность — *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

```
Node* removeDuplicates(Node *head)
{
    Node *t, *p, *i, *prev;
    for(p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        prev = p;
        for(i = p->next; i != NULL; )
        {
            if(i->data == p->data)
            {
                t = prev->next = i->next;
                free(i);
                i = t;
                continue;
            }
            prev = i;
            i    = i->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```